# How can I fix this grid in css?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to do a simple grid for my website. I could almost successfully do what I wanted.
I would like to fix the "Projects" that is the title of this grid, I would like to have it not in the same size as the other parts of the grid.

This is the result that I have:
[image]

I would like to have something like this:
[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="project-container">
      <div className="title">
        <h1>PROJECTS</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="project-one item">
        <h2>Face Recognition</h2>
        <button className="button button1">VIEW PROJECT</button>
      </div>
      <div className="project-two item">
        <h2>Face Recognition</h2>
        <button className="button button1">VIEW PROJECT</button>
      </div>
      <div className="project-three item">
        <h2>Face Recognition</h2>
        <button className="button button1">VIEW PROJECT</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.project-container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  // grid-gap: 4em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "t t t"
    "p1 p2 p3";
}

.item {
  // width: 100%;
  // height: 100%;
  // transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}

.title {
  grid-area: t;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  // height: 10vh;
}
```

Comment: Are the lines of CSS with `//` intended to be commented out? (Those are the wrong comment markers for CSS)

Comment: @DBS maybe he is using preprocessor and copy posted his code from there

Comment: Yes, I'm coding and testing now. There are more styles in the file, just commented out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `grid-template-rows`

```css
.project-container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  // grid-gap: 4em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 100px auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "t t t"
    "p1 p2 p3";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Simple and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Dude I would recommend using **css flexbox**. See I have made a code that might help you & it's fully responsive. If you want to create a heavy masonry layout you can go for css grid.

```css
    .project_container {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: normal 16px/1.9em sans-serif;
}
.wrap {
  color: #292929;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.title {
  background-color: #a2cbfa;
  border: 1px solid #4390e1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #a2cbfa;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
  vertical-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 90, 250, 0.05), 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 90, 250, 0.05),
    0 8px 8px rgba(0, 90, 250, 0.05), 0 16px 16px rgba(0, 90, 250, 0.05);
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  color: #292929;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #a2cbfa;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #a2cbfa;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
  border: 1px solid #4390e1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 90, 250, 0.05), 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 90, 250, 0.05),
    0 8px 8px rgba(0, 90, 250, 0.05), 0 16px 16px rgba(0, 90, 250, 0.05);
  height: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 2%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.project-three {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
button {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-weight: light;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #292929;
  color: #292929;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
   

 <div class="project_container">
      <div class="wrap">
          <div class="title">
            <h1>PROJECTS</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="project-one item">
            <h2>Face Recog</h2>
            <button class="button button1">VIEW</button>
          </div>
          <div class="project-two item">
            <h2>Face Recog</h2>
            <button class="button button1">VIEW</button>
          </div>
          <div class="project-three item">
            <h2>Face Recog</h2>
            <button class="button button1">VIEW</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

*HAPPY CODING*

Regards Sameer